# ppmtogiff: to many colors workaround

Tags: tcl, gif, ppm, quantization

I'm working on a script that takes an .xwd image, runs wxdtopnm on it then pipes that to ppmtogif. Basically:

```
exec wxdtopnm < file.xwd | ppmtogif > file.gif
```

However, sometimes I get an error

```
ppmtogiff: to many colors - try doing a 'ppmquant 256'
```

Well I tried ppmquant and long story short, that option is not avaliable. I stumbled upon **pamdepth** and want to try that. However, I can find no practical examples on how this is properly used and I'm not exactly an expert in tcl.

I tried

```
exec wxdtopnm < file.xwd | pamdepth 6 | ppmtogif > file.gif
```

But that didn't work. I get the message

```
Error: Invalid Command name "6"
```

Could someone show an example of how to properly use pamdepth?

Comment: why gif? try `pnmtopng`. Imagemagick can also handle wxd. Try `convert file.xwd file.gif`

Comment: @FredrikPihl its not my choice, I'm just fixing a bug in someone else's code

Comment: Can you say _how_ things didn't work?

Comment: @DonalFellows good point, updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is going on, it can't be exactly what you wrote:

```
exec wxdtopnm < file.xwd | pamdepth 6 | ppmtogif > file.gif
```

When I try doing the equivalent (for our purposes; I don't have any XWD images around):

```
exec pngtopnm sample.png | pamdepth 6 | ppmtogif >foo.gif
```

I don't get that error you report. Instead, I get:

```
pamtogif: computing colormap...
pamtogif: 121 colors found
```

These are trivial errors caused by the interaction of the fact that `pamdepth` is chatty on its standard error channel (some programs just are) and the fact that Tcl's `exec` turns messages on standard error into error messages by default. That's often the right thing, but we don't want it here. But there's a trivial workaround:

```
exec pngtopnm sample.png | pamdepth 6 2>/dev/null | ppmtogif >foo.gif
```

This redirects standard error *from `pamdepth` only* to the system bit-bucket, leaving the rest of the pipeline to work as expected.

I can't say for sure if this will work for you (I really don't know where that `6` error is coming from!) but it does for me when I try.

Comment: And if I was doing conversion for real, I'd consider using `pnmcolormap` and `pnmremap` directly, as described on the [`pnmquant` manpage](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmquant.html)…